Prepping basement for drywall; how to deal with electrical wires running across joists?
I am renovating my basement and plan on drywalling my ceiling. I am looking to add furring strips across the top of my ceiling to tie my drywall to, but realized a bulk of electrical wires are running diagonally across the bottom of my joists.
What is the best way to get around this without rewiring? only thing that came to mind was running the furring strip until it gets to the wires; then restarting a strip a few inches after, leaving space for the electrical wires and securing it to the joist. I have a feeling this is not ideal and must be a better way.


What you suggest is dangerous, as it hides the live wires from view, but leaves them within reach of nails and screws...

Are you unable to disconnect one end of each cable and run them through a penetration in the joists?

@Huesmann i think the wires will be too short - but i think this is what i will end up doing, and just have to add a junction box

Some of the wiring was run inside the joists, so it looks like this bundle of wires was added sometime after that. Whoever ran this wiring took a shortcut in the interest of getting it done fast and cheap, and probably got away with it because the basement was unfinished.
Those savings now have to be paid back to do it right. Now is the time to bite the bullet, install all of the fixtures (lights, switches, and outlets) where they need to be first, then pull the wiring as required.
The can lights which are in separate rooms created by the new wall will need to be put on separate circuits and you will probably need to install new outlets anyway.
Fixing this in a code-compliant way does not necessarily mean throwing out and replacing all of the wire. Within the same room you might be able to run wire between the fixtures of the can lights using some of the existing wire, and if you can stand the idea of having a few junction boxes visible in your finished ceiling you might be able to re-use more.
If you are a cheapskate like me, you will pull out all of the wire and set it aside, using those lengths of wire where possible to piece things back together. But I would draw the line at adding junction boxes to be able to splice together an 8 foot and a 6 foot piece where a 12 foot piece is required.
I get it: wire is expensive and takes time to install, but you will never have a more convenient time than now, before all of the drywall is up, to get this right. You have the chance now, for probably not as much money as you think, to get the lights and outlets where you want them and the switches where they need to be.

Thanks for the feedback, at the end of the day i agree the best bet is to re-wire with some junction boxes; i already have a few i need to have access to so might see if we can consolidate them together. Time to call an electrician!

I remodeled a basement including adding drywall to the walls. I had the same issue with electrical wires, conduits and plumbing hanging off the bottom of the joists similar to what you have shown. My solution was to install a drop type ceiling with T-bar rails, suspended via wires from the joists, arranged in a manner to support 24 x 24 inch ceiling tiles. This did sacrifice some ceiling height but I found the tradeoff worth while. The T-bars in my case were only about 2.5 inches below the bottom of the joists and this did make it somewhat tricky to install some of the tiles. None the less this approach did leave open the flexibility to be able to take out tiles at a future time to maintain the electrical and plumbing.
After the remodel was completed I soon after did a job change and moved halfway across the country so I never got to see the advantage of the maintainability via the drop ceiling.

There is also a T-bar material that is available to hang drywall too as well. It is practically the same as suspended ceiling T-bar for tile ceilings, but it is dimpled on the mounting face like metal studs are so the screws used don't slip off a smooth surface, hence, driving the installer crazy trying to get the screws started. It will be tough enough due to the overhead situation and how the T-bar likes to move as it is when under pressure from a screw trying to be driven in.

If you are using 1x2 or 2x2 furring strip boards, you have the option of using nail plates (available at your local hardware store). My local Home Depot sells a box of fifty 1.5" x 2.5" plates for under $24.00. They are steel, roughly 16 gauge, have four driving prongs to fasten to the wood. The product is designed to "Protect internal wire runs from nail punctures"

Not a great solution when there is as much wire to be protected as we can see here.
